# How can I install i386/x86 shared libraries on freebsd?

Tags: freebsd, c, shared-library, x86, gdb

GDB is telling me, that the program compiled with `gcc -m32` (i386 program) is incompatible with my shared libraries (i386:x86-64).

Output of `gdb`:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/format
warning: `/libexec/ld-elf.so.1': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
```

It would be nice if someone could explain how to fix this / how to get the libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not tell anything about your system so I'll just make the most likely guess. You are running a 64 bit system and have not installed any 32 bit libraries. The simplest method is to simply add them from the installer:

```
 bsdinstall
```

...and select `lib32`. You can run the installer at any time (not just first install). That's it.

What it does is getting the `lib32.txz` tarball from somewhere like http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/12.1-RELEASE/ and unpack it to `/usr/lib32`. Remember to get the correct version (check with `uname -a`). You can do this manually as well if you prefer. Maybe you already have it available in `/usr/freebsd-dist` or on a DVD.

If you do it manually then you may need to tell `ldconfig` that you have new libraries. Or if you have placed them in unusual locations you need to correct the paths.

```
ldconfig -32 /usr/lib32/ /usr/local/lib32/compat/
```

...or...

```
ldconfig -v -m -R /usr/lib32
```

See [ldconfig(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ldconfig&sektion=8)

You tell very little of why you try to run a 32 bit binary on a 64 bit system. If it is because it was actually made on an older version then you *might* want one of the compatability packages: [misc/compat8x](https://www.freshports.org/misc/compat8x/), [misc/compat9x](https://www.freshports.org/misc/compat9x/), [misc/compat10x](https://www.freshports.org/misc/compat10x/), [misc/compat11x](https://www.freshports.org/misc/compat11x/)

*And just to be sure:* You are aware that you would normally target amd64 (i386-64) on a recent system? `i386` is only 32 bit and we have moved on to 64 bit. This might be trivial to you but with the lack of context in the question I just want to make sure that we are not trying to solve the wrong problem.